# Android CameraX is taking sometime at takePicture() method to capture image

Tags: android, camera, android-camerax

**I am using below code for camera capture from camerax,**

```
    imageCapture.takePicture(outputOptions,
    cameraExecutor,// ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(cntx),
```

Comment: same issue any solution yet?

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to use cameraX with an alternative thread.

Try using it like this:

```
private fun startCamera() {
    binding.previewView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    cameraExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
    val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(requireContext())

    cameraProviderFuture.addListener({
        cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

        val preview = Preview.Builder()
            .build()
            .also {
                it.setSurfaceProvider(binding.previewView.surfaceProvider)
            }

        val imageAnalyzer = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
            .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
            .build()
            .also {
                it.setAnalyzer(cameraExecutor, CodeAnalyser(this@HomeFragment))
            }

        val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA

        try {
            cameraProvider.unbindAll()

            cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                this, cameraSelector, preview, imageAnalyzer
            )

        } catch (exc: Exception) {
            exc.printStackTrace()
        }
    }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(requireContext()))
}
```

By doing this your main thread is not being blocked by the constant image processing.

This is the assumption. You have not shared enough code for me to specifically diagnose your issue.